# React native iOS fonts does not work in any way

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, fonts

**Warning**: This is **not** a duplicate!

I searched and done all the ways that were there.

I use last version of react & react-native(0.55).

All of the methods that were available include the following steps

> 1) Build and create a directory(in the source project): ./assets/fonts
>   2) Run this command: *react-native link*
>   3) Remove ios/build folder
>   4) Run this command: *react-native run-ios*

(In the Xcode ios directory) A directory named **Resources** is created and all fonts are there.

In the **info.plist** file all fonts were added, too.

In **Build Phases >>> Copy Bundle Resources** all fonts were added, too.

This error occurs during project execution:

> unrecognized font family Ananda

There is also an error for the remaining fonts

Please help me really do not know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed this url:

[Fonts in React Native](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e)

Its's working fine. I am using React Native 0.55.4 . Please check your font names.

Comment: It does not work at all. the same fonts work well on Android, but it does not work on iOS

Comment: I am using Muli font and it's working fine on both platforms. Please check your font family for both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

For linking the fonts you can do react-native link .src/assets/fonts if

```
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
```

This should copy all the fonts in your ./src/assets/fonts/ to the ios project library and android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/ folder. In ios it also updates the info.plist file.

Now you have to use the PostScript Name of the font that you linked to use it after rebuilding your project.